# Entity Framework linq to entity slow on code but fast in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, linq-to-entities

The following EF query works slowly in code, but fast in SQL Server Management Studio. How can I rewrite this EF statement to improve execution time?

```
Context.OfferQuotations
          .Include(x => x.OfferRevision)
          .Include(x => x.OfferRevision.OfferParameters)
          .Include(x => x.OfferRevision.OfferParameters.Select(a => a.CostOfFundings.Select(i => i.OfferCostOfFunding.TermRange)))
          .Where(x => x.Id == quotationId);
```

Comment: Please show query which you run in Management Studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem before, so I just turned on `LazyLoading` and `ProxyCreating`.

```
this.Context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
this.Context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;
```

http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/lazy-loading-with-dbcontext.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Turn off lazyloading option of context. Follow this article

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx

then also try to convert your query into join, currently it is working in subquery way.